# Bifurcation diagram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to acquire the bifurcation diagram for the equation below:

[image: formula]

(x is a function of t)

as:

[image]

And here is my snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pitch(r, x):
    return r * x + np.power(x,3)- np.power(x,5)

n = 10000
r = np.linspace(-200, 200, n)
iterations = 1000
last = 100

x = 0

for i in range(iterations):
    x = pitch(r,x)

if i >= (iterations - last):
    plt.plot(r,x, ',k', alpha=0.02)

plt.title("Bifurcation diagram")

plt.show()
```

But the generated plot is not what it is supposed to be:

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is my recent attempt:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pitch(s,x,r):
    x = s[0]
    dxdt = r * x + np.power(x,3)- np.power(x,5)
    return [dxdt]

t = np.linspace(0,100)
s0=[-50]

r = np.linspace(-200, 200)

for i in r:
    s = odeint(pitch,s0,t, args=(i,))
    plt.plot(s,i,',k', alpha=0.02)

plt.title("Bifurcation diagram")

plt.show()
```

With this error:

> raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension") ValueError:
>   x and y must have same first dimension

Could you give me some advice to fix this problem?!

Comment: if $x_0 = 0$, then $x_n = 0$ for all $n$, as you have $x_{n+1} = r x_n + x_n^2 - x_n^3$. On the other hand, for $x_0 \neq 0$, the series diverges exponentially leading to nans.

Comment: @innisfree: Actually, I'm gonna show the bistability of the system, as depicted in the sketch.

Comment: well, ok, but my comment still applies to the series in your first code snippet.

Comment: For the second snippet,  `s = odeint` returns an array of `y` evaluated at every time in `t`, so it's obviously a different length to `i`, which is just a single number. Plotting a single number against a list of numbers results in the error you see.

Comment: have a look here http://systems-sciences.uni-graz.at/etextbook/sw3/bifurcation.html

Comment: @litepresence: Thanks, but in the link you've provided all of the equilibria are easily solvable by analytical approaches. I need a general code for more complicated functions such that the numerical integration will let me get rid of direct computation of the equilibria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link to this post and decided to post a few remarks that might be helpful to someone stumbling upon it in the future.

I did not analyze the equation in detail but it is clear from the first sight that something interesting would happen when `r` is close to 0.

So we could study the behavior of the system for `r in [-10,10]`

You are right to use `odeint` instead of solving the Cauchy problem using Euler method coded by yourself.

This equation has an attractor in that it soon "forgets" the initial condition and slides towards the attractor, yet the choice of the attractor depends on where in relation to 0 do we start. Large positive initial conditions would slide to the negative attractor and vice versa as `- x^5` is the term that defines the behavior at large `x`.

What we need to do is for each r in the range put a mark at the attractor that the solution slides to for each initial condition.

We first create a canvas to put marks into:

```
diagram = np.zeros((200,200))
```

And then for each combination of `(r,s0)` we put a point on the canvas at `(r,s[-1])`.

Here is the complete code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pitch(s,x,r):
    x = s[0]
    dxdt = r * x + np.power(x,3)- np.power(x,5)
    return [dxdt]

t = np.arange(0,100,2)
s0=[-50]

N = 200 # Number of points along each side of the diagram
diagram = np.zeros((N,N))

rmin,rmax = -10,10
rrange = np.arange(rmin, rmax,(rmax-rmin)/N)   

smin,smax = -5.0,5.0
srange = np.arange(smin,smax,2*(smax-smin)/N)    

for i in rrange:
    for s0 in srange:
        s = odeint(pitch,[s0],t, args=(i,))
        imgx = int((i-rmin)*N/(rmax-rmin))
        imgy = int((s[-1]-smin)/(smax-smin)*N)
        imgx = min(N-1,max(0,imgx)) # make sure we stay 
        imgy = min(N-1,max(0,imgy)) # within the diagram bounds
        diagram[imgy,imgx] = 1

plt.title("Bifurcation diagram")
plt.imshow(np.flipud(diagram),cmap=cm.Greys,
           extent=[rmin,rmax,smin,smax],aspect=(rmax-rmin)/(smax-smin))
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel("x")
plt.show()
```

And the resulting plot

[image: Bifurcation plot for the pitch equation]

When you zoom in into the region around 0 by setting `(rmin,rmax)` to `(-0.5,0.5)` you could see that the branches of the diagram do not start at 0

[image: Zooming in around 0]

Instead as in the diagram drawn in the original post the branches start at roughly `r=-0.25`